# ubuntu terminal stuck after running command as root user

Tags: 14.04

I opened the terminal and typed this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webapps/preview
```

It ran it then, I asked for a password. I typed but no letters would show up. The cursor is just remaining blinking. What to do?

Comment: (after you get the password right) It could be trying to connect to some website, I think a PPA needs to download the "actual" server name, the "ppa:webapps/preview" is like a shortcut... Anyone know for sure?

Comment: @Xen2050 yes, `ppa:webapps/preview` will be expanded to `http://ppa.launchpad.net/webapps/preview/ubuntu`.

Comment: @muru Thanks, Is that a standard server for every PPA, so it's just a "cut & paste" change, no downloading required?

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes, given that a PPA only refers to the service Launchpad offers. See http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/software-properties/main/view/head:/softwareproperties/ppa.py#L362 `add-apt-repository` will try to download the public key for the repository.

Comment: @muru "fascinating."  "Adding private PPAs is not supported currently" so they must be the ones that could be anywhere. (unless just the key is private... but why would anyone do that, must not be that). Thanks

Comment: @Xen2050 No, they still follow the same URL pattern (different server: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/), but require more authentication (a username/password combination).